# getting keyboard events without the window being focused

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-events

i want to get keyboard events without having focus.
my application is a background application and should send "space" key to another app when user presses CTRL+space in any application.
i use .NET and i use C# as language.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to create a [global keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).